# C++ and standard containers: memory addresses of members

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, stdvector

I am currently having some trouble with my understanding of the memory management in standard containers, especially `std::vector`.

It is clear to me that `std::vector` will resize after adding an element to it if there is not enough space reserved, therefore moving each element and changing the addresses in memory. My question is now: what happens to the element's member variables?

My problem is based on the idea that for my game engine I am currently managing scenes in a `std::vector`. The scenes are managed by a `Scene` manager class that contains a `std::vector` of `Scene`s. Adding of scenes looks like this:

```
    std::vector<Scene> scenes;
    Scene* active;
...
        Scene scene;
        scenes.emplace_back(scene);
        active = &scenes.back();
```

The scenes are stack-allocated and will be thrown away after leaving the method. For exposing the currently added scene to the outside I am storing a pointer to the back of the `std::vector` which is the newly inserted element.

`Scene`s contain various members, for example an instance of the `Light` class. I also expose pointers to those elements to the outside for various reasons. My problem was that I tried to use those pointers in the constructor of the `Scene` which got constructed in the `Scene` manager. After adding the object to the `std::vector` a new object seems to be constructed even if the `Scene` constructor doesn't seem to be called. The "active" member now contains an different memory address than the actual `Scene` object I allocated before. As the vector needs to resize I am clear with that I think.

But what happens to the members of the scene? The original `Scene` will be destructed, the active element got another memory address. That means it points to an whole new element because of the internal resize and that new element has new members and are in my case those I want to work with.

Am I right with my understanding?

My second question includes how I should handle situations like that where I want to expose pointers to members of objects stored in a `std::vector` with unknown size. My current method of choice works just fine but I am not sure if it is the right way to do:

In the `Scene` class there is an `onActivate` event method which will just be called after the whole resizing and getting the inserted element of the vector has finished. When I switch the active pointer that method will be called, too. That method takes the pointers to the members of the scene and passes them around. It looks something like that:

```
void postConstruct() {
    std::cout << "postConstruct: " << &el << std::endl;
}
```

And will be called at the right place in the `Scene` manager which currently is a `friend` to the `Scene` class because those events should not be exposed to the outer world.

```
    active->postConstruct();
```

Is this the right way to go?

Comment: Remember that when a `std::vector` needs to enlarge itself, it can *reallocate* the memory used. That means all iterators *and pointers* to elements become invalidated and can no longer be used. Saving a pointer to an element of a vector is therefore not a good idea.

Comment: The value of the pointer to the vectors' element is intended to be always refreshed after resizing the vector and the only way to access an vectors' element from the ouside. I am planning on replacing the vector with an map later on but for now I am fine with that method of accessing.

Comment: I need to explicitly keep track of one element. I am not sure if the stl containers are the right thing to use for later but for now that's my situation.

Comment: By "preserving the addresses", are you asking whether vector elements keep the same address? Or whether their pointer members keep the same value after being moved/copied?

Comment: "...moving each element and preserving the addresses in memory."  No.  I have seen that the memory address of an element is not preserved.  I believe the index to existing vector elements is preserved with vector expansion.  i.e. push_back (beyond current capacity) creates a new contiguous allocation, and adds the one new index.  But there are  many implementation details involved.   Example: on ubuntu, with g++, an expansion (caused by a push-back) doubles the contiguous memory.

Comment: After a quick test I found out that I was wrong with preservation of the memory addresses. So there is a chance that the vector could be completely reallocated in another contigous memory block and therefore each element could get new addresses assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `vector` is expanded, all iterators, pointers and references to elements become invalid. The **only** defined thing you can do with an invalid pointer or iterator is overwrite it with another value, and there is **nothing** you can do with an invalid reference. Even *comparing* the value to some other value makes your program *ill-formed*.

When you do

```
Scene scene; 
scenes.emplace_back(scene); 
active = &scenes.back();
```

You have *two* `Scene` objects. One is a local variable, the other is in the vector, and was *copied* from `scene`. I'm not sure that you are aware of this distinction, you probably only want *one* `Scene` object. Either all `Scene`s live in `scenes`, or you change it to be a `std::vector<Scene *>`, or a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Scene>>`. If you do the latter, make sure to remove values before they are destroyed.

The language provided copy constructor will simply copy the *value* of each member, which in the case of pointers, will tend to be the wrong thing. You can explicitly define a copy constructor for `Scene` to control exactly what happens, e.g. "deep copy" pointer members.

```
class Copyable
{
    int* ptr;
public: 
    Copyable() : ptr(new int) {}
    ~Copyable() { delete ptr; }
    Copyable(const Copyable & other) : ptr(new int(*other.ptr)) {} // deep copy
    Copyable& operator=(const Copyable & other)
    {
        *ptr = *other.ptr;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you can prohibit the copying of `Scene`s by defining the copy constructor as `= delete`d

```
class UnCopyable
{
    int* ptr;
public: 
    UnCopyable() : ptr(new int) {}
    ~UnCopyable() { delete ptr; }
    UnCopyable(const UnCopyable & other) = delete;
    UnCopyable& operator=(const UnCopyable & other) = delete;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In case the `std::vector` is resized, the elements will be either moved using element's move constructor if the move constructor is declared as `noexcept` or it would be copied using element's copy constructor to the newly allocated position.

Whether the member pointers will be same after reallocation will depend upon how the move constructor or copy constructor is implemented for the element being inserted.

I would suggest using index than `Scene*` to access the elements in `std::vector` or use `std::list` if you want to use `Scene*`

Comment: I thought of that, too. So as I am not having an explicitly defined copy or move constructor the default copy constructor seems to be used which will only copy the member variables' values to new memory locations. Seems that to be correct?